# Connect with GoogleApiClient though it has already been connected

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-api-client

I am working in an android application where i am using GoogleAPI . In `OnCreate()` method ,

i connect with the `GoogleApiClient` . My question is : Suppose , `GoogleApiClinet` is `connected`. Now if in another method , i call for the connection with `GoogleApiClient` again , will it create any problem with the `speed` & `performance` of my application ?

Again i am using `Geofencing` also . suppose , some places are registered with `Geofence`. I call again the method to register with the same places & it does not create any problem . But my question is , will it create any harm internally or make my application `slow` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not create any harm with your application. I suggest you to check this [Accessing Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client) documentation for it.

It is stated here that when you want to make a connection to one of the Google APIs provided in the Google Play services library (such as Google Sign-In, Games, or Drive), you need to create an instance of GoogleApiClient ("Google API Client"). The Google API Client provides a common entry point to all the Google Play services and manages the network connection between the user's device and each Google service.

Here is the sample code that uses `GoogleApiClient` with multiple API and scope.

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                      this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
    .addApi(Drive.API)
    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
    .build();
```

You can add multiple APIs and multiple scopes to the same GoogleApiClient by appending additional calls to [`addApi()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder#addApi) and [`addScope()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder#addScope(com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope)).

If you want to connect the `GoogleApiClient` Manually, then this [part](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client#manually_managed_connections) of documentation can help you with that.